# Как сделать мгновенное перестроение диаграммы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Добрый день.
Сейчас диаграмма перестраивается с самого начала, когда изменяется значение - она перестраивается, как сделать так, чтобы она перестраивалась не с нуля, а с того значения на котором она остановилась до этого? (На изменение диаграммы влияет первый ползунок)

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var tarif = 5,
    client = 1,
    revenue = 0,
    check = 4000,
    date = 1,
    RevenueGrowth = 0,
    rent = 0,
    percentage = 0,
    ClientsGrowth = 0,
    RentPerMonth = 0,
    TransactionCosts = 0,
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = 0;
  // Функция расчета
  function recount() {
    $(function() {
      $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
          table: 'datatable'
        },
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          title: {
            text: 'Units'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
              this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
          }
        }
      });
    });
    // Считаем приост клиентов
    ClientsGrowth = client * 0.3;
    // Округляем переменную до целого числа
    ClientsGrowth = +ClientsGrowth.toFixed();
    // Считаем аренду терминала, преобразуем в строку, и переписываем строку так чтобы был пробел каждые три символа
    rent = String(date * RentPerMonth).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Считаем расходы по транзакциям
    TransactionCosts = ((client + ClientsGrowth) * check * date) / 100 * tarif;
    // Считаем прирост выручки от терминала
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = check * date * ClientsGrowth;
    // Преобразуем строку в число и округляем чсило до целого
    TransactionCosts = +TransactionCosts.toFixed();
    // Считаем чистую выручку преобразуем в строку и округляем ее до целого значения
    revenue = (((client + ClientsGrowth) * date * check) - TransactionCosts).toFixed();
    // Переписываем так чтобы был пробел каждые три символа
    revenue = revenue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Преобразуем в строку и переписываем так чтобы бы пробел каждые три символа
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = String(RevenueGrownthTerminal).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Выводим данные
    jQuery("#revenue span").html(revenue + ' руб');
    jQuery("#ClientsGrowth span").html(ClientsGrowth + ' чел.');
    jQuery("#rent span").html(rent + ' руб.');
    jQuery("#TransactionCosts").html(TransactionCosts);
    jQuery("#RevenueGrownthTerminal span").html(RevenueGrownthTerminal + ' руб.');
    jQuery("#tarifpercentage span").html(tarif + ' %');
  };
  // Вызываем функцию расчета
  recount();
  // Если в #tarif изменилось значение то выполняется функция:
  jQuery('#tarif').change(function() {
    tarif = jQuery('#tarif option:selected').val();
    RentPerMonth = 0;
    if (tarif == 3.3) {
      RentPerMonth = 300;
    } else if (tarif == 2.2) {
      RentPerMonth = 900;
    }
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#client", function() {
    client = +$(this).val();
    $("#client-slider").slider("value", client);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#check", function() {
    check = +$(this).val();
    $("#check-slider").slider("value", check);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#date", function() {
    date = +$(this).val();
    $("#date-slider").slider("value", date);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
});
// Слайдер 1
$(function() {
  $("#client-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 300,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $('#client').val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#client").val($("#client-slider").slider("value"));
});
// слайдер 2
$(function() {
  $("#check-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 4000,
    min: 1,
    max: 500000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#check").val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#check").val($("#check-slider").slider("value"));
});
// слайдер 3
$(function() {
  $("#date-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 60,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#date").val($("#date-slider").slider("value"));
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #34a3db;
}
#tarif {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
#datatable {
  display: none
    }
span {
  color: #91e8fc;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
  border-color: #6b6b6b;
}
.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #c1c2c4;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
.ui-slider-range {
  background: #34a3db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Jane</th>
      <th>John</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Apples</th>
      <td id="TransactionCosts"></td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Pears</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Plums</th>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bananas</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Oranges</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="choise_tarif">
    <p>Выберите тариф</p>
    <p>
      <select id="tarif">
        <option value='5'>Базовый</option>
        <option value='3.3'>Профессиональный</option>
        <option value='2.2'>Корпоративный</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Клиентов в месяц:</label>
    <input type="text" id="client" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="client-slider"></div>

  <p>
    <label for="amount">Средний чек на 1-го клиента:</label>
    <input type="text" class="check" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="check-slider"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Срок использования терминала:</label>
    <input type="text" id="date" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="date-slider"></div>
  <p id="revenue">Ваша чистая выручка: <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
  <p id="RevenueGrownthTerminal">Прирост выручки от использования терминала: <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
  <p id="rent">Аренда терминала: <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
  <p id="tarifpercentage">Процент по транзакциям <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
  <p>Невидимые на сайте значения:</p>
  <p id="ClientsGrowth">Прирст клиентов: <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
  <p id="">Расходы по транзакциям: <strong><span></span></strong>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: зачем вам ready() внутри ready()? и зачем вы подключаете две версии jquery?

Comment: Не понял насчет ready, можно подробнее?

Comment: Видимо Jean-Claude имел в виду то, что вы использовали `jQuery( callback )` внутри которого вызывается `$( callback )`, а эти операции в свою очередь алиас `$( document ).ready( callback )`. Про это можно прочитать [вот здесь](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), если коротко, то `callback` вызовется когда DOM загрузится. Итого, когда они вложены, получается несколько некрасиво, вы должны это понимать)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел решение сам,

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var tarif = 5,
    client = 1,
    revenue = 0,
    check = 4000,
    date = 1,
    RevenueGrowth = 0,
    rent = 0,
    percentage = 0,
    ClientsGrowth = 0,
    RentPerMonth = 0,
    TransactionCosts = 0,
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = 0;
  // Функция расчета
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
      responsive: true,
      tooltipXPadding: 10,
      tooltipYPadding: 6,
      tooltipFontSize: 18,
      scaleLabel: "<%= '$' + value%>",
      tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%>$<%= value %>",
      multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %>: $<%= value %>",
      legendTemplate: '<ul>' + '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>' + '<li>' + '<span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span>' + '<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% } %>' + '</li>' + '<% }$ %>' + '</ul>'
    });

  function recount() {
    myBar.datasets[0].bars[0].value = client;
    myBar.datasets[1].bars[0].value = date;
    myBar.datasets[2].bars[0].value = ClientsGrowth;
    myBar.update();
    // Считаем приост клиентов
    ClientsGrowth = client * 0.3;
    // Округляем переменную до целого числа
    ClientsGrowth = +ClientsGrowth.toFixed();
    // Считаем аренду терминала, преобразуем в строку, и переписываем строку так чтобы был пробел каждые три символа
    rent = String(date * RentPerMonth).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Считаем расходы по транзакциям
    TransactionCosts = ((client + ClientsGrowth) * check * date) / 100 * tarif;
    // Считаем прирост выручки от терминала
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = check * date * ClientsGrowth;
    // Преобразуем строку в число и округляем чсило до целого
    TransactionCosts = +TransactionCosts.toFixed();
    // Считаем чистую выручку преобразуем в строку и округляем ее до целого значения
    revenue = (((client + ClientsGrowth) * date * check) - TransactionCosts).toFixed();
    // Переписываем так чтобы был пробел каждые три символа
    revenue = revenue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Преобразуем в строку и переписываем так чтобы бы пробел каждые три символа
    RevenueGrownthTerminal = String(RevenueGrownthTerminal).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
    // Выводим данные
    jQuery("#revenue span").html(revenue + ' руб');
    jQuery("#ClientsGrowth span").html(ClientsGrowth + ' чел.');
    jQuery("#rent span").html(rent + ' руб.');
    jQuery("#TransactionCosts span").html(TransactionCosts + ' руб.');
    jQuery("#RevenueGrownthTerminal span").html(RevenueGrownthTerminal + ' руб.');
    jQuery("#tarifpercentage span").html(tarif + ' %');
  };
  // Вызываем функцию расчета
  recount();
  // Если в #tarif изменилось значение то выполняется функция:
  jQuery('#tarif').change(function() {
    tarif = jQuery('#tarif option:selected').val();
    RentPerMonth = 0;
    if (tarif == 3.3) {
      RentPerMonth = 300;
    } else if (tarif == 2.2) {
      RentPerMonth = 900;
    }
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#client", function() {
    client = +$(this).val();
    $("#client-slider").slider("value", client);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#check", function() {
    check = +$(this).val();
    $("#check-slider").slider("value", check);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
  // Вывод данных из слайдера, при условии что он был сдвинут, слайдер выдает переменную в виде строки, преобразуем ее в число добавив унарный +
  $(document).on("change keyup", "#date", function() {
    date = +$(this).val();
    $("#date-slider").slider("value", date);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    recount();
  });
});
// Слайдер 1
$(function() {
  $("#client-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 300,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $('#client').val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#client").val($("#client-slider").slider("value"));
});
// слайдер 2
$(function() {
  $("#check-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 4000,
    min: 1,
    max: 500000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#check").val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#check").val($("#check-slider").slider("value"));
});
// слайдер 3
$(function() {
  $("#date-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 60,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#date").val($("#date-slider").slider("value"));
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #34a3db;
}
#tarif {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
#datatable {
  display: none
}
span {
  color: #91e8fc;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  background-color: #6b6b6b;
  border-color: #6b6b6b;
}
.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #c1c2c4;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}
.ui-slider-range {
  background: #34a3db;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bar Chart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 50%">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>


  <script>
    var barChartData = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        label: "COST",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65]
      }, {
        label: "REVENUE",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28]
      }, {
        label: "PROFIT",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28]
      }]

    }
  </script>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="choise_tarif">
      <p>Выберите тариф</p>
      <p>
        <select id="tarif">
          <option value='5'>Базовый</option>
          <option value='3.3'>Профессиональный</option>
          <option value='2.2'>Корпоративный</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
      <label for="amount">Клиентов в месяц:</label>
      <input type="text" id="client" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>

    <div id="client-slider"></div>

    <p>
      <label for="amount">Средний чек на 1-го клиента:</label>
      <input type="text" id="check" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>

    <div id="check-slider"></div>
    <p>
      <label for="amount">Срок использования терминала:</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>

    <div id="date-slider"></div>
    <p id="revenue">Ваша чистая выручка: <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
    <p id="RevenueGrownthTerminal">Прирост выручки от использования терминала: <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
    <p id="rent">Аренда терминала: <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
    <p id="tarifpercentage">Процент по транзакциям <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
    <p>Невидимые на сайте значения:</p>
    <p id="ClientsGrowth">Прирст клиентов: <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
    <p id="TransactionCosts">Расходы по транзакциям: <strong><span></span></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="js/calculator.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Может ответ не совсем в тему, но по моему скромному мнению вы не сможете в этом чарте вносить новые данные без его перестроения не лезя в ядро скрипта.

Вам изначально нужно было подобрать чарт, в котором в инициализационных параметрах есть доступ к вводимым данным. Как пример нашел первый попавшийся чарт и сделал то, что вам необходимо. Код скопирован с этой странички http://canvasjs.com/ , вставлен ваш ползунок и прописано обновления после изменения ползунка.

```js
$(function() {
  var client = 1;

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "theme2", //theme1
    title: {
      text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"
    },
    animationEnabled: false, // change to true
    data: [{
      // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: [{
        label: "apple",
        y: client
      }, {
        label: "orange",
        y: 15
      }, {
        label: "banana",
        y: 25
      }, {
        label: "mango",
        y: 30
      }, {
        label: "grape",
        y: 28
      }]
    }]
  });
  chart.render();

  $('#client').on("change keyup", function() {
    client = +$(this).val();
    $("#client-slider").slider("value", client);
    // Вызываем функцию расчета, чтобы пересчитать после зменения 
    //console.log(client);
    //console.log(chart);
    console.log(chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[0].y = client);
    chart.render();
  });

  $("#client-slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 300,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $('#client').val(ui.value).trigger("change");
    }
  });
  $("#client").val($("#client-slider").slider("value"));

});
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <p>
    <label for="amount">Клиентов в месяц:</label>
    <input type="text" id="client" readonly style="border:0; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="client-slider"></div>
</body>
```